# How to use microphone on headset in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, pulseaudio, microphone

I used Realtek Audio manager in case of Windows and I was able to use my the microphone that is integrated with my head-phones.

I have installed PulseAudio Volume Control. But it doesn't show up in the input devices section.

Edit : I want the system to detect it as a headset rather than a headphone.
Here's the screenshot of PulseAudio
[image]

Here's the input device list. Only microphone is present in the drop down list.
[image]

Comment: If your headphones/earphones have a mic attached it should have a three ring jack that plugs into the computer. If that's the case and your computer doesn't accept three rings it will only see it as an audio playback device. Are you trying to use your headphones AS microphones? If that's the case, just plug them into the microphone jack and your computer should see them a microphone.

Comment: Did you use the ear-phones, or the ear-phone connector, but with a microphone, or both?

Comment: Just using the earphones. Can listen to the output audio but can't record using the mic on the earphone.

Comment: Yes, it has a three ring jack. The OS should detect it as a headset rather than a headphone. That's what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: You are showing output devices in your screenshot, but you are looking for a microphone which is an input device. Do you see anything in the input devices section?

Comment: No, it just says 'Microphone'. When I click on the dropdown icon, only microphone is present.

Comment: I edited your question for you (you can also do this), to reflect some of what you told us in the comments.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this answer - https://superuser.com/a/1329331/965902

Create or edit `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` and add the following:

`options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi`

Reboot. After reboot, you may have to detach and attach headset again. In my case, on doing this, Ubuntu asked me with a menu what I attached, so I selected "headset". And it worked.